# Can a senior collecting Social Security get a disability tax exemption?

Tags: united-states, taxes, social-security, new-york, long-term-disability

I'm looking into some of the tax exemptions for my mother. She pays a ton in local and school taxes, so much she can barely afford it. I was reading about the disability exemption described here:

https://www.tax.ny.gov/pit/property/exemption/disablexempt.htm

She gets Social Security, and not disability, but she does have a heart condition, and it's difficult for her to get around due to a bad knee. I'm wondering if she would qualify for this exemption, and if so, how I would go about getting her on it?

Comment: What's her annual income?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the NY page on Exemptions for Persons with Disabilities](https://www.tax.ny.gov/pit/property/exemption/disablreqmnt.htm), she must either qualify for SSDI or SSI, or one of a few other programs.  She must be able to submit one of these forms:

> - Award letter from the Social Security Administration certifying the applicant's eligibility to receive Social Security Disability Insurance (SSDI) or Supplemental Security Income (SSI)
> - Award letter from the Railroad Retirement Board certifying the applicant's eligibility to receive railroad retirement disability benefits
> - Certificate from the State Commission for the Blind and Visually Handicapped stating that the applicant is legally blind
> - Award letter from the United States Postal Service stating that the applicant is certified to receive a United States Postal Service disability pension
> - Award letter from the United States Department of Veterans Affairs stating that the applicant is entitled to a veterans disability pension

She must also have an income less than $29,000 per year, including her social security income.  Different municipalities may have other restrictions (including a lower income limit), or may expand a smaller break to people above the limit, but you'd have to check with your local revenue authority for their specific rules.